# Ubuntu server internet connection

Tags: server, virtualbox, windows-8, internet, usb-modem

Im using windows 8 with USB Internet Connection.

I have installed ubuntu server using Virtual Box.

In Virtualbox Network setting i tried all types of connections.

Still ubuntu server is not getting connected to internet.
If i type 
`PING GOOGLE.COM` it gives me `Unknown Host`

Looks like Ubuntu server in virtual box will not detect USB Internet connection.

How do i configure Ubuntu Server in Virtualbox to detect my USB Internet connection?

Comment: Actually in your case it's the other way around. You have to configure your windows OS to share the connection and act as a gateway for your network and then point the Ubuntu VM to that gateway by means of a virtual network card. If you use USB passthrough (and assuming you find the appropriate drivers for it to work under Ubuntu) the device can only be available on one OS at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed VirtualBox guest additions? If not, install it and then try.
Do you want internet to work on both windows as well as on ubuntu server?
If installing virtualbox guest additions also does not work, you can try creating virtual box network connection with "virtio net" driver.